# warning: declaration does not declare anything

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm getting a strange warning in my interface file.

[image]

This is also coming at the line where I declare the property for this.

[image]

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: First of all, there is no reason to declare ivar and property. Second, where in your interface file are you declaring this?

Comment: Are these variables a part of some enumeration or structure?

Comment: Also, since it looks like you're using this variables possibly with CGRects or some other CoreGraphics, you should probably use CGFloat so you can match type with Apple's properties.

Comment: On OS X, to support i386, it is necessary to declare an ivar for the property. This is not true on OS X for the x86_64 runtime, however, or on iOS. As of now, @Aaron has not specified the target platform.

Comment: @dbrajkovic I'm declaring this in @ interface{float xOffset; float yOffset } @ end

Comment: @bneely when I checked this site http://www.raywenderlich.com/2712/using-properties-in-objective-c-tutorial it said "Always make a property for every instance variable".

Comment: Aaron: on iOS, or on OS X when supporting only x86_64, that is an unhelpful generalization. Not all ivars need accessor methods, which is what the @property declaration is -- it replaces the declaration of getter and setter methods. What about an ivar for a button that is loaded from a nib/xib? There's rarely a valid reason to create getter/setter methods for that.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in your project, you have a `#define` that defines `xOffset` to be nothing (except maybe a comment).  Something like this:

```
#define xOffset
```

or this:

```
#define xOffset // hello
```

If you command-click on `xOffset` where you're getting the warning (or control-click it and choose “Jump to Definition” from the pop-up menu), Xcode should jump to the `#define`.

Comment: You will need to check harder.  Try putting `float;` in your program and you'll see that it gives you the warning you're seeing.

Comment: I noticed your line numbers are in the hundreds.  You probably have some sort of typo somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I just created a class, compiled, and no error. Here is the entire implementation file.

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface MHAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
{
    float xOffset;
    float yOffset;
}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (assign) float xOffset;
@property (assign) float yOffset;

@end
```